# Adding only one title at a time to the table header in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

So I created a to do list website and one of the features is creating a title to your to do list. I created a function that allows the user to enter a title and submit it, however the user can do this multiple times. I want the user to only submit a title once and cannot submit again unless they delete the title first. I did this all in jquery and the function is under `//Creating a list name`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyYbZL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, just add the disabled attribute to the submit button in your onclick function, then remove that attr if they delete the title.

```
$(".btn-primary").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

then

```
$(".btn-primary").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Edit: Here's a fork of your code.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYqbBZ

Comment: Sorry, i have been learning jquery for only a week and a half where would I put the `.addClass` in `$(".btn-primary").on("click", function(e)`?

Comment: You're the man thanks! If you have any more time would know how to move the delete to the right side of the title instead of underneath?